# downloading guice3.0 artifact from maven central repository

Tags: maven, struts2, guice, maven-jetty-plugin, guice-3

I'm trying to upgrade my struts2 web app from guice2.0 to guice3.0. 
I'm trying to test it out using maven jetty. 
I've successfully upgraded my pom.xml to use the correct version and groupId for the 3.0 release, but if I call mvn jetty:run
I see that it is trying to download 
guice-3.0-no_deps.jar

which throws a build error and can't be found the central repository?

I don't get this error if I don't include any guice extensions.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide a minimum pom file to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question also to the guice user group. 
This is the answer I received.

The guice-3.0-no_deps.jar is a build-time artifact that's used to compile the extensions, but is not required at runtime - it's not on maven central because the Guice team didn't want people depending on this "uber-jar" by mistake. The extensions have an optional dependency to guice-3.0-no_deps.jar (so they can compile) but they also have a non-optional dependency to guice-3.0.jar for the runtime case.

Well-behaved maven plugins should see that the the no_deps dependency is optional and not throw a build error if it's missing, so this sounds like a bug in the jetty plugin. To workaround the Jetty bug you can explicitly hide this dependency as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-struts2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Note that we can't do this in the original build pom because we still need the no_deps dependency when doing the original compilation.